# Simulating DELETE cascades with WeakHashMaps

Tags: java, dictionary

I'm developing a service that monitors computers. Computers can be added to or removed from monitoring by a web GUI. I keep reported data basically in various maps like `Map<Computer, Temperature>`. Now that the collected data grows and the data structures become more sophisticated (including computers referencing each other) I need a concept for what happens when removing computers from monitoring. Basically I need to delete all data reported by the removed computer. The most [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)-like approach would be removing the data manually from memory, like

```
public void onRemove(Computer computer) {
    temperatures.remove(computer);
    // ...
}
```

This method had to be changed whenever I add features :-( I know Java has a [`WeakHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/WeakHashMap.html), so I could store reported data like so:

```
 Map<Computer, Temperature> temperatures = new WeakHashMap<>();
```

I could call [`System.gc()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#gc--) whenever a computer is removed from monitoring in order have all associated data eagerly removed from these maps.

While the first approach seems a bit like primitive MyISAM tables, the second one resembles [DELETE cascades in InnoDB tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html). But still it feels a bit uncomfortable and is probably the wrong approach. Could you point out advantages or disadvantages of `WeakHashMaps` or propose other solutions to this problem?

Comment: Can you show why and how you changed the `onRemove` method when adding a feature? That would help clarify what your actual problem is...

Comment: @assylias Well I'd need to remove data from all my maps (temperatures, neighbours, operating systems, local users, ...). Actually I do have more entities than `Computer` that produce data and have to be removed once the user removes them from monitoring.

Comment: There are several problems with your idea pointed on several answers but there is one more. `System.gc()` is not guaranteed to do anything at all. See this bug report http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6668279 I do use WeakHashMap to store metadata about objects that may be removed so I need less maintenance of those maps but that an object has not been removed from WHM should not mean anything at all. You can never know if GC has tried to collect (destroy) that object or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if it is possible for your case, but couldn't your Computer class have all the attributes, and then have a list of `monitoredComputers` (or have a wrapper class called `MonitoredComputers`, where you can wrap any logic needed like `getTemperatures()`). By that they can be removed from that list and don't have to look through all attribute lists. If the computer is referenced from another computer then you have to loop through that list and remove references from those who have it.

Comment: That's indeed another solution: Either storing computer related data in the computer object itself or in some `ComputerReport` object which is _strongly reachable_ only through the (monitored) computer object.

Comment: Yes, exactly. It might sometimes be easier to restructure the model when you realize that you are interested in another type of cross section of the data.

Comment: what do you mean by cross section?

Comment: Cross section was probably the wrong word, what i mean was what to group the data on, what is the primary data Are you working with temperatures, or are you working with computers.

Analog: Should you map a person to several bands, or should you map a band to several persons. i.e. it depends on how you work with the data and what type of operations/views you want to present.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure using a WeakHashMap is a good idea. As you say you may reference Computer objects from several places, so you'll need to make sure all references except one go through weak references, and to remove the hard reference when the Computer is deleted. As you have no control over when weak references are deleted, you may not get consistent results.

If you don't want to have to maintain manually the removal, you could have a flag on Computer objects, like `isAlive()`. Then you store Computers in special subclasses of Maps and Collections that at read time check if the Computer is alive and if not silently remove it. For example, on a `Map<Computer, ?>`, the get method would check if the computer is alive, and if not will remove it and return null.

Or the subclasses of Maps and Collections could just register themselves to a single computerRemoved() event, and automatically know how to remove the deleted computers, and you wouldn't have to manually code the removal. Just make sure you keep references to Computer only inside your special maps and collections.

Comment: "As you have no control over when weak references are deleted, you may not get consistent results." --> Removing a Computer doesn't happen often, `System.gc()` is acceptible in this case. Keeping `Temperatures` encapsulated in some special object that listens to `computerRemoved` events however might be a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use an actual SQL database?  You could use an embedded database engine such as [H2](http://h2database.com), [Apache Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/) / [Java DB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javadb/overview/index.html), [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org), or [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org).  Using an embedded database engine has the added benefits:

1. You could inspect the live contents of the monitoring data at any time using the corresponding DB engine's command line client.
2. You could build a new tool to access and manipulate the data by connecting to a shared database instance.
3. The schema itself is a form of documentation as to the structure of the monitoring data and the relationships between entities.
4. You could store different types of data for different types of computers by way of schema normalization.
5. You can back up the monitoring data.
6. If you need to restart the monitoring server, you won't lose all of the monitoring data.

Your Web UI could use a JPA implementation such as Hibernate to access the monitoring data and add new records.  Or, for a more lightweight solution, you might consider using Spring Framework's [`JdbcTemplate`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#jdbc-JdbcTemplate) and [`SimpleJdbcInsert`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#jdbc-simple-jdbc-insert-1) classes.  There is also [OrmLite](http://ormlite.com), [ActiveJDBC](http://javalite.io/activejdbc), and [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org) which each aim to offer simpler access to databases than JDBC.

Comment: Because the computers are accessed quite often (multiple times per minute) and the GUI will access them among other entities via WebSockets so the displayed temperatures per computer will update as soon as they are reported. I don't think, this is easy with an in-memory database.

Comment: @steffen:  Oh, so you do not have historical data, only the most current readings?

Comment: Primarily only current data! I'd store historical data somewhere else because that would consume too much memory).

Answer (score 1):

The problem with WeakHashMap is that managing the references to Computer objects seems difficult and easily breakable.

> Hash table based implementation of the Map interface, with weak keys. An entry in a WeakHashMap will automatically be removed when its key is no longer in ordinary use. More precisely, the presence of a mapping for a given key will not prevent the key from being discarded by the garbage collector, that is, made finalizable, finalized, and then reclaimed. When a key has been discarded its entry is effectively removed from the map, so this class behaves somewhat differently from other Map implementations.

It could be the case that a reference to a Computer object might still exist somewhere and the object will not be deleted for the WeakHashMaps.  I would prefer a more deterministic approach.

But if you decide to go down this route, you can mitigate the problem I point out by wrapping all these Computer object keys in a class that has strict controls.  This wrapper object will create and store the keys and will pay attention to never let references of those keys to leak out.

Comment: Well I'd say that if there's another strong reference to a Computer, and it won't be removed from the `WeakHashMap` is as deterministic as if there are only strong references. -- On the contrary: Bugs (strong references to Computer that were forgotten to be removed) show up immediately as the entry in the `WeakHashMap` remains.

Comment: If someone issues a request to delete a Computer you can't really do it if there are references to Computer still in memory.  So it is important you manage that.

Comment: If it's possible that a reference to Computer remains somewhere, then you have a memory leak. It's better to have something that fails immediately rather than at some random point in time. Especially if it's a service that runs 24/7.

Comment: Saying, "no its ok if it does not work we will have other problems that we may notice eventually" does not seem right.  the fact you are expecting to have this all in memory, meaning every Computer object will be in memory, then having a second reference to it will not surface as a fail-fast memory leak, since a reference does not take up a lot of memory, vs the object itself.  either way I am not saying don't do it, I'm saying pay attention to this potential problem by making sure you do not keep a reference accidentally.

Comment: here is a good test to try out.  when the command to delete is issued, then start making requests for the object to see how long it takes for it to disappear.  you will also have to take into account the JVM you are using, since the results may differ based on the JVM you are using.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. When a strong reference remains after deletion you might end up with a memory sink: the strong reference prevents the JVM to free the object memory (itself, not just the reference). A WeakHashMap can tell you easily that you missed a reference: If the WeakHashMap contains the object after deletion, it indicates the object is still strongly reachable.

Answer (score 0):

Novice coder here, so maybe this is too clunky:

Why not keep the monitored computers in a HashMap, and removed computers go to a WeakHashMap? That way all removed computers are seperate and easy to work with, with the gc cleaning up the oldest entries.

Comment: This doesn't address the problem. Also I don't see why you would want to put the computers in `WeakHashMap`, they won't be garbage collected until all strong references are nulled.